# Adding InMobi dependency with version like 'number.x x' into Android project gives error

Tags: android, gradle, admob, inmobi

I'm trying to integrate InMobi network into Admob. Documentation says to add such dependency

`compile 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.x.x'`

into build.gradle but it gives an error

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.x.x
```

Solution like answered. Every time you add a dependency make sure version is set explicitly by change the x with specific value.

Comment: What document are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this in your gradle file the last two x.x are actually latest versions of library.

> compile 'com.inmobi.monetization:inmobi-ads:7.0.1'

also add

```
  allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

in project level build.gradle

Comment: Yep correct, version did the job done. They should have added that on website!